# delimited file txt file from sql2008 table

Tags: python

Every day I need to query my sql2008 and export a file with the name + date. It has to be a Tab Delimited file.

I can't use `BCP` for various reasons. I can export the data into a text file as str etc. but not into tab delimited. I know I need to use csv but how? And there a way to get the `headers` out as well in Tab delimited?

Python Code:

```
fout = open('filename', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(fout, dialect='excel-tab')

con = dbconnect.connectdb()
cursor = con.cursor()

sql="select * from table"

cursor.execute(sql)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
   writer.writerow(row)
```

I connect to db just fine, run my command but get the following error
    `writer.writerow(row)`
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

I just need everything in the table in tab delimeted so I can ftp to the vendor. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you got your code from a Python 2.x example and now run with a 3.x version. The csv module interface has changed and now the file must be opened with:

```
fout = open('filename', 'w', newline='')
```

The error was caused because you opened the file in binary mode and it expected only byte strings and not unicode strings which are the normal strings in Python 3.